# Trouble installing ADT in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have followed the instructions for installing the ADT in Eclipse and all goes well until the last step - 
Select Window > Preferences and choose Android from the left panel.

Android does not appear in the left panel!

What am I missing?

Some details:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers- Version: Helios Service Release 1

Android Development Tools   16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group

Answer (score 0):

Once you've installed the ADT you may need to restart eclipse.

Comment: I have: resstarted Eclipse, re-installed JDK, Eclipse, ADK, ADT, Turned off virus checking and fire wall. Also tried ity on 3 machines 2 runnig Windows XP one running Vista. Could it be a 32 bit issue?? Frustrating - should not be this hard!